# Insights API giving Fans count as 0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, count

From the last few days, Facebook insights API is giving Fan count as 0 for certain dates and when queried for Fan count for the same dates after few days, insights API is giving the count. Is there a bug with insights API for this abnormal behaviour?

Insights API used to work without any issues so far and from the past 15 days or so I have noticed this abnormal behavior.

Please help regarding this if any one has any idea about this abnormal behavior.

Thank you,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

I have also this bug too, additionally for the other metrics deprecated as said in FB. Two days before I could get page_fans for January 3-5,2012 but after 10 minutes of that it was gone ! 
Also I noticed that in the queries in FB.api we wrote, end_time has to be written like a UNIX time ie 12423492349 not like 2011-01-03 in this function. I think this end_time function becomes a bug for the API and now there is no of that.